# Ubuntu localhost issue

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Now I know that there are plenty of posts on setting up localhost in Ubuntu with apache2 and PHP.

However, I have been racking my brains for around 2 hours and I've had about enough now.

This is basically a test site; I want to see if it works with the url

`personalisedchampagnestore.localhost`

I have installed apache2 and php5. I have tested localhost, which works with the default html page.

P.S. These are similar to the defaults, so I've stripped a lot of it out

I have then configured the following files:

**apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/personalisedchampagnestore/PersonalisedChampagneStore/web/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**sites-available/personalisedchampagnestore.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName personalisedchampagnestore

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/personalisedchampagnestore/PersonalisedChampagneStore/web/


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/personalisedchampagnestore/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/personalisedchampagnestore/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and finally

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   personalisedchampagnestore
127.0.1.1   liam-VirtualBox

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

After saving, I have restarted apache2, enabled the site using `sudo a2ensite personalisedchampagnestore`, and enabled mod_rewrite using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. I've also removed the .htaccess and added in a blank index.html page, but I still get the following error:

```
Server not found

Firefox can't find the server at www.personalisedchampagnestore.localhost.
```

I also have looked in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file and there isn't anything there. Also, I've looked in the error log I set up which is `/var/log/apache2/personalisedchampagnestore/error.log`, and this file is completely empty.

Has anyone got any suggestions? I assume this is something very tiny that I have missed and I will end up kicking myself.

**Edit:**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2014 17:08:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: what is `127.0.0.5`?? If your stuff is running on the same host use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: i did, but it wouldn't work so i put something completely random in hope it needed to be different. Changed it to 127.0.0.1 so i will update my question

Comment: `firefox` is trying to connect to `www.personalisedchampagnestore.localhost` but you don't have it in your /etc/hosts. Put it in /etc/hosts and change the apache `ServerName` to `www.personalisedchampagnestore.localhost` as well.

Comment: @alvits It automatically adds the www. In front for some bazaar reason. I'll give it a go though

Comment: Just realised, my htaccess is probably redirecting to www, I'll check in the morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offcourse, you need to make sure `www` is not included in the url (due to .htaccess file).

1. In `sites-available/personalisedchampagnestore.conf` file, the `ServerName` mentioned is `personalisedchampagnestore`

1. In `/etc/hosts` file, the registered host is `personalisedchampagnestore`
2. So all you need to write in the browser address bar is - 
   `http://personalisedchampagnestore`

and it should work fine.

If you want the url to be `http://personalisedchampagnestore.localhost`, then please make the following changes -

1. In `sites-available/personalisedchampagnestore.conf` file, change the below line -
   `ServerName personalisedchampagnestore` 

   `with`

   `ServerName personalisedchampagnestore.localhost`
2. In `/etc/hosts` file, change the below line -

   `127.0.0.1   personalisedchampagnestore`

   `with`

   `127.0.0.1   personalisedchampagnestore.localhost`

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, i was being a halfwit by assuming it automatically had to put localhost on the end. But logically, I don't know why i assumed this. Thank you